# Rails: Shoulda matcher, Minitest and Devise query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, minitest, shoulda

Rails 5.1.6
Ruby 2.5.0

I am trying to run a simple test for a redirect in one of my controllers using Shoulda Matcher gem (following the documentation) and minitest:

home_controller.rb:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController



def index
#redirect on login
 if user_signed_in?
    redirect_to controller: 'home', action: "dashboard_#{current_user.user_role}"
 end 
end
```

test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:

```
class HomeControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
             context 'GET #index' do
              setup { get :index }


              should redirect_to(action: "dashboard_#{current_user.user_role}")
            end
        end
```

Error:

```
Undefined method current_user for homecontrollertest
```

I'm using Devise and was wondering if anyone could assist to get my test to work? I can provide more info if required.

**EDIT:**

Tried this:

home_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

    class HomeControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
      include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

      context 'GET #index' do
        user = users(:one)
        sign_in user
        get :index 
        should redirect_to(action: "dashboard_#{user.user_role}")
      end
    end
```

users.yml

```
one:
name: 'John'
email: 'some@user.com'
encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
user_role: 1
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'shoulda', '~> 3.5'
gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.0'
```

Test_helper.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all


  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Get undefined method users error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for HomeControllerTest:Class
/mnt/c/code/studytaps/test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:HomeControllerTest>'
/mnt/c/code/studytaps/test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:8:in `<class:HomeControllerTest>'
/mnt/c/code/studytaps/test/controllers/home_controller_test.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include devise test helper to your test

```
class HomeControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

  context 'GET #index' do
    user = users(:one) # if you use fixtures
    user = create :user # if you use FactoryBot
    sign_in user
    get :index 
    should redirect_to(action: "dashboard_#{user.user_role}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an error "undefined method users" when I use "user = users(:one)" ?

Comment: Updated original question.

Comment: @Co2, do you have `fixtures :all` line in your test_helper.rb? Do other fixtures work in your tests?

Comment: Yup I do. I must be missing something more fundamental. I'm using Rails 5. But I can't figure out what :/

Comment: Added Gemfile and Test_helper to first post if helps? I have no more tests currently.

Comment: @Co2, could you please add full error, as you get it after run `rake test`

Comment: Added to opening post. Is that what you need?

Comment: @Co2, sorry, not sure why your fixtures does not load :( Try to run `spring stop` maybe. And try to add `fixtures :users` to the test itself. Is your `users.yml` inside `test/fixtures` folder?

Comment: Yes, in the right places. Apparently I am supposed to include this in rails_helper.rb? But I don't have this file?  Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
    config.integrate do |with|
      # Choose a test framework:
      with.test_framework :minitest
      with.library :rails
    end
  end

Comment: I have answer :) Was using context block instead of test block in controller. Thank you so much for your help though. :)

Comment: @Co2, ouch, I missed it when copy-pasted your code :( Anyway, happy to help you